# iPad always assuming portrait-width as max-width

Tags: html, ipad, css, media-queries

I am building an reponsive-website, having 3 sizes. Max 480px, max 768px and max 1024px+; 
However, I have a problem when using the iPad. On a Galaxy Tab 10.1 it works like a charm, in my browser it works also good.. but it seems that whenever I use the iPad it always seems think the max-width is 768px.

This is what I mean:
[image: Explenation]

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    background-color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: green;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
    body {
        background-color: brown;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1023px) {
    body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}

</style>
<body>
<div class="color">
    Some color
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Although my requirements do not include iPad support, I do want to support it.

Comment: This has probably to do with `max-scale`, `min-scale` and `initial-scale` - try setting all of these to 1 and see if anything changes. When you rotate the iPad it doesn't change the viewport, rather it scales the content. Does reloading the page in landscape work?

Comment: That acutally did help a lot, I still have a white border to the right of the page, but I can live with that. Add is as an answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has probably to do with max-scale, min-scale and initial-scale - try setting all of these to 1 and see if anything changes.

The downside is that iOS users won't be able to pinch to zoom in your page.

When you rotate the iPad it doesn't change the viewport, rather it scales the content. There is a good explanation from [Allen Pike](http://www.allenpike.com/2010/choosing-a-viewport-for-ipad-sites/).